# How can I transform a column in r under a certain length?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a product number category that has a lot of different values and rows for each value.

Example is

282 rows of A1
23 rows of A3
1 row of y7
3 rows of x56.

I'm trying to run a for loop to change the label to "other" for products with under 5 rows. The code I have now is:

```
for (i in unique(color$Fabric)){
  if (length(color$Fabric[color$Fabric == i]) < 5){
      color$Fabric[i] <- 'Other'
  }
}
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Fabric", value = c("Other", "Other",  : 
  replacement has 4470 rows, data has 4469
```

I have also tried:

```
for (i in unique(color$Fabric)){
  if (length(color$Fabric[color$Fabric == i]) > 5){
      color$FabricNew[i] <- i
  } else {
    color$FabricNew[i] <- "Other"
  }
}
```

and I get the same error.

I know its a forrest through the trees syntax error thing but I'm kinda stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The looping is on `unique` values  and it is not an index for 'Fabric'.  We could do this more easily by using `table` to get the frequency count of each of the unique elements of 'Fabric', Then subset those having less than 5 count, create a logical vector with `%in%` on the 'Fabric' and assign those to 'Other'

```
tbl1 <- table(color$Fabric)
color$FabricNew <- color$Fabric
color$FabricNew[color$Fabric %in% names(tbl1)[tbl1 <= 5]] <- "Other"
```

---

In the OP's code, if we change it to

```
un1 <- unique(color$Fabric)
color$FabricNew <- color$Fabric
for(i in seq_along(un1)) {
    i1 <- color$Fabric == un1[i]
    if(sum(i1) <= 5) {
       color$FabricNew[i1] <- 'Other'
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good use case for `fct_lump_min` which will do this automatically for you.

```
df <- data.frame(col = factor(rep(letters[1:4], c(10, 2, 13, 4))))

table(df$col)

# a  b  c  d 
#10  2 13  4
```

Now let's keep the values that occur only 5 times and turn rest of them to `'Other'`.

```
df$col <- forcats::fct_lump_min(df$col, 5)

table(df$col)
#    a     c Other 
#   10    13     6
```